# Eagle-i website citations in BibTex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, code

I'm trying to cite some information from the Eagle-i website using BibTex. I realized they have many types of citations that seems not to match the BibTex entry types. For example, Eagle-i suggested the following format for ANTIBODIES:

Owning organization name, Institution name (if needed). Antibody name. Resource type. Other resource identifier(s), if applicable. eagle-i ID.

As an example of citation they have:

> Oregon Stem Cell Center Monoclonal Antibody Core. Oregon Health and Science University. HPi1 monoclonal antibody supernatant from hybridoma HIC0 4­F9. Monoclonal antibody. http://ohsu.eagle-i.net/i/0000012b­3b41­4b21­62b8­f47280000000.

So I'm trying to figure out a way to represent that in BibTex and I've come up with:

```
@Misc{kestest,
author = {Oregon Stem Cell Center Monoclonal Antibody Core.},
title = {Oregon Health and Science University.},
howpublished = {HPi1 monoclonal antibody supernatant from hybridoma HIC0 4F9.}, 
month = {Monoclonal antibody.},
note = {http://ohsu.eagle-i.net/i/0000012b3b414b2162b8f47280000000.},
}
```

The problem here is that this is obviously an inconsistent approach, I'm just putting the information in the tags so the result will be displayed in the order that I want.

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem? The ideal would be making something like this work:

```
@antibodies{kestest,
orgname = {Oregon Stem Cell Center Monoclonal Antibody Core.},
institute = {Oregon Health and Science University.},
name = {HPi1 monoclonal antibody supernatant from hybridoma HIC0 4F9.}, 
type = {Monoclonal antibody.},
id = {http://ohsu.eagle-i.net/i/0000012b3b414b2162b8f47280000000.},
}
```

Thank you.

Links:

Citing an eagle-i Resource: https://www.eagle-i.net/get-involved/for-researchers/citing-an-eagle-i-resource/